# Center one background image over the other in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I have 2 background images and i want to position image1 over image2 in such a way that first is centered on the second. (image1 is caution symbol and image2 is the blue background). The end result should look like the image below.

[image: Expected Image]
But I am getting my image like this.
[image: Real Image]

My code is below:

**CSS**

```
.imgPin {
  background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  height: 39px;
  width: 31px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 11;
  &.active {
    opacity: 1.0;
    z-index: 12;
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
 var divElem = document.createElement("div");
 divElem .setAttribute( 'style', 'background: url( "caution.png" ), url("background.png")' );
 divElem .className = "imgPin";
```

Is there a way to set the background size or the repeat in such a way that this could be achieved? Any help would be invaluable.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

My final css looks like this and its working:

```
.imgPin{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:60% 30%,center;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  height: 39px;
  width: 31px;
  background-size:auto,100% 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 11;
  &.active {
    opacity: 1.0;
    z-index: 12;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is this? background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;

Comment: in the JS change background with background-image

Comment: @rach8garg each one for each background since he has multiple one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your JS, you are specifying `background` which will override all the background properties specfied in the CSS. So instead use `background-image` to keep the CSS properties:

```
var divElem = document.createElement("div");
 divElem .setAttribute( 'style', 'background-image: url( "caution.png" ), url("background.png")' );
 divElem .className = "imgPin";
```

Then you may need to adjust the CSS if you still have alignment issue:

- Use `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain` to avoid the icon to stretch or simply don't specify any size to keep the original ones.
- Add `background-position:center` in order to center both icons. You can also specify values in order to control position like this `background-position: 5px 10px,10px 5px` (works also with % values).
- Then specify `background-repeat:no-repeat` (only once and it will affect both images)

Comment: What u mentioned has worked but now the caution image is elongated like this? https://gyazo.com/831330e4282f5c66e46ae1c203449c06. How to center it on the blue image?

Comment: @SRINI794 now adjust background-size like this `cover` or use `contain`

Comment: @SRINI794 alsoe add `background-position:center`

Comment: Much better now looks like this. https://gyazo.com/c94bb1af64b6bceca8db79ac03b2fc88 But how to rescale the caution image so that it looks like the expected image in the original question?

Comment: @SRINI794 well try to remove the backgroun-size, don't use it and center the icon like i mention before

Comment: Excellent. It looks like this now. https://gyazo.com/6022a8e470225f8872aeca1c4b41d7dc    How do i translate the caution image in y coordinates so that i would like to have it in a desired position as the expected image ?

Comment: @SRINI794 with background size you can do this `background-size:10px 20px, 10px 20px` or use % values then adjust as needed ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164748/discussion-between-srini794-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 1):

The second background repeats, so change this property:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;
```

to

```
background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
```

(and fine-tune the size and/or position)

Comment: well, i guess it won't have effect as he used 100% with background size ... he need to correct his JS

Answer (score 0):

Your second background image has repeating property.

It should be updated as follows.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

Comment: it won't have effect, he's using background in his JS wich will override this and the other background properties

Comment: Then perhaps need to apply both fixes.